# Date formatting a Ruby date from a .NET Webservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a date coming through from a .NET webservice into my Rails app:

```
2011-05-09T10:57:00+01:00
```

What date format can I use with Date.strptime which would give me a reliable way of extracting the date?

Comment: How would you like the date formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date and DateTime can handle this natively:

```
DateTime.parse "2011-05-09T10:57:00+01:00"
# => Mon, 09 May 2011 10:57:00 +0100
```

Answer (score 0):

@Chowlett's answer is good Or you can also try out the "strptime" method on Date. It lets you parse a string in a know format of your choosing.

http://santoro.tk/mirror/ruby-core/classes/Date.html#M000643